# Conditional ? : SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

```
(ISNULL([Deal Status]) ? "2" : SUBSTRING([Deal Status],1,1)) == "2"
```

This is one of the outputs in a conditional split in SSIS.

I Don't understand what this means. Could you help explain this?

I understand: If Deal Status is null, return 2, else check if dealstatus is 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `? and :`, it's a conditional operator, the same as using an if/else statement:

```
condition ? true result : false result
```

So to breakdown what your statement is doing, it first checks to see if `DealStatus IS NULL`.  If so, it returns a "2".  If it isn't `NULL`, it returns the first character of the `DealStatus` field using `SUBSTRING`.  Finally, it compares that result to see if it's equal to "2".

The overall expression will return a true/false.  For example, if `DealStatus` is `NULL`, this will always return true.

---

For example, here would be the results if the following values were stored in the DealStatus field.

```
DealStatus    ResultOfCondition
NULL          true (because DealStatus is NULL, we compare 2 == 2 is true)
123           false (because the first character is 1, 1 == 2 is false)
234           true (because the first character is 2, 2 == 2 is true)
```

Comment: But then.. so what is the output of this particular conditional split? Is it where dealstatus is null or where deal status is 2?

Comment: @Sarah -- I've updated the answer to try to help better explain.  When DealStatus IS NULL, it compares 2 to 2, and returns true.  If DealStatus is not NULL, it compares the first character of DealStatus to 2, and returns true or false accordingly.

Comment: Sgeddes, 
does it mean that the output will include:
All deals where deal status is null AND
All deals where first char of DealStatus is 2?

Answer (score -1):

For example, here would be the results if the following values were stored in the DealStatus field.

DealStatus=null

**(ISNULL([Deal Status]) ? "2"** : SUBSTRING([Deal Status],1,1)) == "2"
it will verifies the first condition, DealStatus value is null so it will display(true condition) the after ? value whatever is there , In this scenario "2" is there  after "?" it will display the 2.so 2=2

DealStatus=256

(ISNULL([Deal Status]) ? "2" : **SUBSTRING([Deal Status],1,1)) == "2"**

it will checks the first condition, but DealStatus value is not null so it will check the second condition it will produce the out put is 2 .so 2=2.

Substring Ex:-

Select SUBSTRING('258',1,1) o/p:- 2

Select SUBSTRING('589',1,1) o/p:- 5